# Object moves left to right but does not go right to left

Tags: python, pygame

The object is currently moving left to right but not left to right.
I cannot find the error in my code.

The code is:

```py
class Ball:

    def __init__(self, pp_game):

        self.screen = pp_game.screen
        self.settings = pp_game.settings

        self.color = self.settings.ball_color

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(14,400, self.settings.ball_width, self.settings.ball_height)
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
          
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)


    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right <= self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ball_speed
            self.rect.x = self.x
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left >= self.screen_rect.left:
            self.x -= self.settings.ball_speed
            self.rect.x = self.x

    def draw_ball(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

I have set a two conditions for each if statement.

The `self.moving_left`/`self.moving_right` changes when a key is press i.e spacebar

I call the update function like this:

```
def run_game(self):

    while True:
        self._check_events()
        self._update_screen()
        self.player_a.update()
        self.player_b.update()
        self.ball.update()
```

This is an image of the screen:

[image]

The blue and red are players and yellow is the ball.

I think there is a typo or if there is an error can you please help me find it.

If there is anything you can't understand , please ask me.

Comment: So where do you change the direction of the ball?

Comment: Do you possibly _set_ `moving_left` but do not _reset_ `moving_right`...?

Comment: Firstly I press a key which changes the moving_right then when it reaches the end of the screen i.e the right border then I press the other key which activates moving_left, which minuses the whole distance the object traveled (placing it back to its original position) but it does not move back

Comment: @CiaPan I think the object stops moving right when it reaces the right border but i think i understand what you mean like when I try to minus the distance it get added again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not enough to "activates" `moving_left`. You must also "deactivate" `moving_right`:

Move left:

```py
self.moving_right = False
self.moving_left = True
```

Move right:

```py
self.moving_right = True
self.moving_left = False
```

When both states are set, the ball moves in both directions. This will compensate either movement and the ball will not move at all.

Therefore it is easier to have 1 attribute that indicates the direction of movement:

```py
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, pp_game):
        # [...]

        self.move_x = 0

    def update(self):
        if self.move_x > 0 and self.rect.right <= self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ball_speed
            self.rect.x = self.x
        if self.move_x < 0 and self.rect.left >= self.screen_rect.left:
            self.x -= self.settings.ball_speed
            self.rect.x = self.x
```

Set `move_x = 1` when you want to move to the right and `move_x = -1` when you wan to move to the left.